# How to retrieve arraylist from hashmap with particular value from onlistview click in android?

Tags: android

I am adding an array to hashmap with particular value.
I am unable to retrieve the values from arraylist with particular value from on listview click item.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<SeatList>> example = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<SeatList>>();

    ArrayList<SeatList> seatlistarray;

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

**Item and SeatList are bean classes.**

///////////////////////////////

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)

  {          

    Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

     Node seat=(Node)seatlist.item(k);

                                if(seat.hasChildNodes()){

                                    NodeList seats=seat.getChildNodes();


                                    for(int m=0;m<seats.getLength();m++){

                                        Node seatf=(Node)seats.item(m);

                                        if (seatf.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {



                                            HashMap hash=new HashMap();

                                            Element eElement = (Element) seatf;
                                            seatlistarray=new ArrayList<SeatList>();

                                            hash.put("ID", eElement.getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0).getTextContent());
                                            hash.put("X_pos", eElement.getElementsByTagName("X_pos").item(0).getTextContent());
                                            hash.put("Y_pos", eElement.getElementsByTagName("Y_pos").item(0).getTextContent());
                                            hash.put("Radius", eElement.getElementsByTagName("Radius").item(0).getTextContent());


                                        seatlistarray.add(new SeatList(eElement.getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0).getTextContent()));

                                        }}}}

                            example.put(parser.getValue(e, "Hall-ID"), seatlistarray);


                             items.add(new EntryItem(parser.getValue(e, NODE_NAME), parser.getValue(e, NODE_DESIGNATION),parser.getValue(e, "Hall-ID")));
}
```

**Here listview on click listener function:**

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        if(!items.get(position).isSection()){

            EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);

            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.VenueName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             ListIterator<SeatList> testExtracted = example.get(item.HallID).listIterator(); 

             if(testExtracted.hasNext()){

                System.out.println("MYUID:"+testExtracted.next().getID());

            }


        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // try this
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
        {

            Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

            Node seat=(Node)seatlist.item(k);

            if(seat.hasChildNodes()){

                NodeList seats=seat.getChildNodes();

                seatlistarray=new ArrayList<SeatList>();
                for(int m=0;m<seats.getLength();m++){

                    Node seatf=(Node)seats.item(m);

                    if (seatf.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {



                        HashMap hash=new HashMap();

                        Element eElement = (Element) seatf;


                        hash.put("ID", eElement.getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0).getTextContent());
                        hash.put("X_pos", eElement.getElementsByTagName("X_pos").item(0).getTextContent());
                        hash.put("Y_pos", eElement.getElementsByTagName("Y_pos").item(0).getTextContent());
                        hash.put("Radius", eElement.getElementsByTagName("Radius").item(0).getTextContent());


                        seatlistarray.add(new SeatList(eElement.getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0).getTextContent()));

                    }
                }
                example.put(parser.getValue(e, "Hall-ID"), seatlistarray);
                items.add(new EntryItem(parser.getValue(e, NODE_NAME), parser.getValue(e, NODE_DESIGNATION),parser.getValue(e, "Hall-ID")));
            }
        }



    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            if(!items.get(position).isSection()){

                EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);

                Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.VenueName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ArrayList<SeatList> list =  example.get(item.HallID);

            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this it will get only last item.ArrayList<SeatList> list =  example.get(item.HallID);
      
      for(SeatList lists:list){
       
       System.out.println(lists.getID());
       
      }